# Beamer: mode* and own frame definition

Tags: beamer

Say that I am using my own definition for question frames, something akin to

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Malmoe}

\newcommand{\questionframe}[2]{
    \frame[c,plain]{
        \centering\huge
        \textbf{\structure{#1}}
        \par\bigskip
        #2
    }
}
\begin{document}
\questionframe{Here is the question?}{And corresponding explanation}
\end{document}
```

However, within `\mode*`, which is super useful to my environment, these frames will get ignored. From the documentation:

> The text is gobbled 209 token by token until one of the following
>   tokens is found: `\mode`, `\frame`, `\againframe`, `\part`, `\section`,
>   `\subsection`, `\appendix`, `\note`, `\begin{frame}`, and `\end{document}`
>   (the last two are really tokens, but they are recognized anyway

What is the easiest way to reconcile the two - i.e., forcing beamer to stop gobbling around when it meets `\questionframe`?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Malmoe}

\newcommand{\questionframe}[2]{
    \frame[c,plain]{
        \centering\huge
        \textbf{\structure{#1}}
        \par\bigskip
        #2
    }
}
%
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\preto\beamer@treat{\ifx\beamer@nexttoken\questionframe\let\next=\beamer@stopoutsidemode\fi}{}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\mode*

\questionframe{Here is the question?}{And corresponding explanation}

\begin{frame}
abc
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```